# Create custom scheduler k8s

Tags: python, kubernetes, scheduler

I've seen a lot of implementation of custom scheduler however all of them use a old api version. is it possible to create k8s scheduler running in a pod?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Scheduler is also a pod running in the kube-system namespace by default.

You can [run multiple schedulers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/) simultaneously alongside the default scheduler and instruct Kubernetes what scheduler to use for each of your pods